# Backup Database and push to TFS server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs

Is that a way that i can schedule to run a SQL agent job to generate the database schema and data script file and then check in to the Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it backwards. You [push the database generation script into source control](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/), and generate the database from the source script. If you find yourself trying to do the reverse, *you're doing it wrong*.

Comment: not necessarily.  If you're working from a legacy database, that can be impractical.  Trust me, I've learned that lesson the hard way.